# How do I get github to diff against the target and not from the base of the branch?

Tags: git, github

I have the following branch that I want to diff against master to see the changes to track down a bug (not really relevant which one). When I compare the latest commit in my branch with the latest commit in master I don't get the expected result: https://github.com/SaturnFramework/Saturn/compare/ee91e7c86051d3bc6812b0a51523bf69bea8a05a...mastoj:ef9c17a3f9cb12df9b9a56ee4a60a5fce21603e9

One concrete example is this line: https://github.com/SaturnFramework/Saturn/compare/ee91e7c86051d3bc6812b0a51523bf69bea8a05a...mastoj:ef9c17a3f9cb12df9b9a56ee4a60a5fce21603e9#diff-b27553841b4413a24ed1b9aff865105bL26

If I browse the code in the base that line is found here: https://github.com/SaturnFramework/Saturn/blob/ee91e7c86051d3bc6812b0a51523bf69bea8a05a/paket.dependencies#L26

and in my branch it is here: https://github.com/mastoj/Saturn/blob/ef9c17a3f9cb12df9b9a56ee4a60a5fce21603e9/paket.dependencies#L26

and they are identical. So why does the diff on github say that they differ? I know my code differs from where I branched, but it is identical to the where I want to do the merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the tripple dot notation for the comparison. In Git, that's

```
git diff ee91e7c...ef9c17a
```

According to `man git-diff` that's:

> This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second `<commit>`, starting at a common ancestor of both `<commit>`. `git diff A...B` is equivalent to `git diff $(git merge-base A B) B`.

However, what you want is the double dot notation, or simply two arguments:

```
git diff ee91e7c..ef9c17a
# or
git diff ee91e7c ef9c17a
```

Which is:

> This is to view the changes between two arbitrary `<commit>`.

---

For the equivalent result on Github, try this link: https://github.com/SaturnFramework/Saturn/compare/ee91e7c86051d3bc6812b0a51523bf69bea8a05a..mastoj:ef9c17a3f9cb12df9b9a56ee4a60a5fce21603e9

Comment: For `git diff`, double-dot loses its special meaning, and becomes the same as just giving two separate commit specifiers.

Comment: @torek does it really lose its meaning, or does it (coincidentally) just do the same thing?

Comment: Well: consider that `git log A..B` never shows you revision A at all, but depending on how many revisions are selected, does show many different revisions "after" (descendant-from) A, up through and including B. Meanwhile `git diff A..B` compares the snapshot in revision A to the snapshot in revision B. If `git diff` were to act like `git log,` it should compare each commit in `A..B`, as listed *by* `git log`, *to* revision B. So if `git log A..B` prints four revisions, you should get four separate diffs—or just three since B-vs-B is silly—none of which compares `A` to `B`

Comment: Meanwhile, `git diff` with the *three*-dot notation does something different from `git log` yet again. (This code is considerably more special-case-y in the `git diff` source.  The actual code has evolved more than once, and the `A..B` case is now handled by calling the internal revision parser: try `git rev-parse A..B` and `git rev-parse A...B` to see what that returns.)

Comment: @torek I updated the answer to refer to `man git-diff` instead. I wonder why they decided to use the same syntax as the range specification, even with those inconsistencies...